# How do I get SQLAlchemy 1.1 to print out the query results?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm running the following query:

```
s.query(db.Order, db.Execution).join(db.Execution).all()
```

Which produces an output that looks like:

```
[(<db.Order at 0x7fd061efeda0>, <db.Execution at 0x7fd061789780>),
 (<db.Order at 0x7fd061efeda0>, <db.Execution at 0x7fd061789b38>),
 (<db.Order at 0x7fd061efee48>, <db.Execution at 0x7fd061789550>),
 (<db.Order at 0x7fd061efeb00>, <db.Execution at 0x7fd061789630>),
 (<db.Order at 0x7fd061efeb00>, <db.Execution at 0x7fd061741400>),
 (<db.Order at 0x7fd0603bdcf8>, <db.Execution at 0x7fd060de3c88>),
 (<db.Order at 0x7fd0603bdcf8>, <db.Execution at 0x7fd060de3c18>),
 (<db.Order at 0x7fd0603bdcf8>, <db.Execution at 0x7fd060de3860>),
 (<db.Order at 0x7fd061efe4e0>, <db.Execution at 0x7fd0617412e8>),
 (<db.Order at 0x7fd0603bdcf8>, <db.Execution at 0x7fd060de3710>),
 (<db.Order at 0x7fd0603bdcf8>, <db.Execution at 0x7fd060de35c0>),
 (<db.Order at 0x7fd061f13438>, <db.Execution at 0x7fd061741ba8>)]
```

It looks right, but is there an easy way to actually see the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to receive instances of objects, then you see *actual* results already.

If, however, you would like to have more user-friendly view, then you should implement [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__).

If what you want is to see some columns, then specify columns instead of the whole objects, and you will get only those columns (values). For example:

```
s.query(
    db.Order.id, 
    db.Order.name, 
    db.Execution.date, 
    db.Execution.type.label("execution_type"),
).join(db.Execution).all()
```

If you really would like all columns of your query, then you could do the following as well:

```
q = s.query(db.Order, db.Execution).join(db.Execution)
q = s.execute(s.subquery())
```

Answer (score 1):

try to implement the method **repr** in your SQLAlchemy mapped objects (Order and Execution).
Supposing that your Order object has an "id" attribute, this is what you might want to do:

```
#...inside class Order
def __repr__(self):
    return "<Order(id=" + str(self.id) + ")>")
```

HTH

C

Answer (score 1):

İf you need to see the result you can use for, the query returns a list as you can see every element has an Order and an Execution object. Therefore you can access object attribute:

```
result = s.query(db.Order,db.Execution).join(db.Execution).all()
for r in result:
    print(r.Order.id, r.Execution.id)
```